# Close IntelliJ IDEA JavaScript autocomplete

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ Idea 14 and have a nodejs project. I install a lot of node modules in the project, and when I write code in js file, it is so slow. Enter two or three character idea will stop 1s but other file (like css) is ok.

How to disable js file validation or is there other way to optimize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of disabling javascript inspections and autocomplete at all, it is just better to exclude node JS modules folder from your sources. This way Idea still processes your own files in the project but not the huge amount of third party libraries.

> Right click on node folder → Mark directory as → Excluded